# Update MS graph extension properties

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have an extension with a custom field like this in the MS Graph Api:

```
 {
            "id": "8cd-d9e8-4625-ac96-de8d2",
            "deletedDateTime": null,
            "appDisplayName": "",
            "dataType": "String",
            "isSyncedFromOnPremises": false,
            "name": "extension_5b087af1548c4d01842ff07d1_TenantId",
            "targetObjects": [
                "User"
            ]
        },
```

When I go to an App registration and add the key `extension_5b087af1548c4d01842ff07d1_TenantId` in the manifest I do get:

> The following extension properties are not available for the given
> resource: extension_5b087af1548c4d01842ff07d1_TenantId.

I believe the reason is, that the `targetObjects` does not include "Application". It just says "User". Two questions:

1. Is this the reason for the error message?
2. How can I update the `targetObjects` to reflect "Application" as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try to send `PATCH` request to `/v1.0/applications/{app_id}/extensionProperties/{extension_id}` endpoint and in the body specify the property and values to be updated. You need to know the app id.

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{app_id}/extensionProperties/8cd-d9e8-4625-ac96-de8d2

{
    "targetObjects": [
        "User",
        "Application"
    ]
}
```

I didn't find any documentation related to updating extension properties, so not sure if it's only missing of the update is not supported.

**Update**

Update is not supported and it fails with the message

> Data contract version does not allow 'Update' operations against
> instances of resource 'ExtensionProperty'.

The extension property must be deleted and re-created with correct `targetObjects`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work: "Data contract version does not allow 'Update' operations against instances of resource 'ExtensionProperty'." So the case is to delete it and add it again?

Comment: @Torben I was afraid that update is not possible. In that case you need to delete and re-create extension property.